# Different brokerage accounts for HSA, IRA, 401(k), misc.?

Tags: brokerage, online-brokerage

I truly cannot find this information on my brokerage website.

I have a brokerage account for my HSA, and if I wanted to use this same brokerage to invest cash I have sitting in my bank acct. would I:

1. transfer into this previously-created account that I linked to my HSA custodian
2. create a new "Individual" account?

I'm assuming the 2nd (from colloquial knowledge and common sense), but I'm confused why my brokerage would offer the option to "transfer cash from a bank account" to my HSA-linked account.

I use TDAmeritrade.

## EDIT:

To clarify this question, in a first attempt to transfer cash to a new non-retirement account w/TDAmeritrade, the website took me to a page with the option of transferring cash to my HSA-linked account. Seeing this option, I was confused if I did that how TDAmeritrade would sort through my HSA contributions vs. transferred cash? Or if I would have to do that on my own? So I came here to see if it was common that people would just "transfer cash" to their retirement accts via brokerage... I didn't think so, but I couldn't find any info on the TD website.

Comment: If you could not transfer money into your HSA account how would you contribute to it for health spending?

Comment: @Vality My issue was that I hit my contribution limit and my brokerage was offering me the option to transfer cash to a HSA-linked brokerage account. I was confused by the option, but am slowly realizing it's just probably something they didn't think through when designing their website.

Comment: Ah, I see. It isn't usually the brokerage's responsibility (nor do they definitely know, IE if you are married etc) how much you are allowed to deposit. Some do enforce this but ultimately it is your responsibility to not deposit too much and they dont have to stop you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not completely clear what you're asking, but if you're asking if TDAmeritrade can hold your HSA and IRA, the answer is probably "yes" (note that your *employer* determined where your 401(k) is held, so the answer there is "only if that's the custodian your employer selects").

If you're asking if you can just "transfer" cash to your HSA, then that would be a *contribution* and would be subject to the rules and regulations regarding HSA contributions. You can't think of your HSA as a "catch-all" account that you can invest cash and other retirement funds in, the same way you can't arbitrarily invest cash into your IRA - that, too, would be a contribution and subject to eligibility.

So I *think* the answer you're looking for is yes, you could create individual brokerage (non-retirement) and IRA accounts and contribute (or roll over) funds to both of them, but you can't commingle them in one account.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying in my question, but yes! You answered my Q here: `You can't think of your HSA as a "catch-all" account..` This is mostly what I assumed, but **in a first attempt to transfer cash to a new non-retirement account w/ TD, it took me to a page with the option of transferring cash to my HSA account.** Seeing this option, I was confused if I did that how TD would sort through my HSA contributions vs. transferred cash? Or if I would have to do that on my own? So I came here to see if it was common that people would just "transfer cash" to their retirement accts via brokerage.